# Redefinition and fail to use ifned/def/endif

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-code, header

I'm trying to make a program that follows the following UML diagram
[image: My UML diagram]

I've divided each class into its respective header and cpp. However, while doing some tests on it I found plenty of messages of redefinition so I tried using ifndef, def and endif however as you can see in this image (my commission worker header) it seems as if I wasn't including the employee header at all [image: ComisionWorker header]

I'm using Visual Studio Code if that's relevant (Also, I doubled checked my file's name so that's not the problem)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Comment: Your problem is not in the code that is shown. It's in the code you don't show. I suspect you named the include guard the same in more than 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the header file for the Employee Class by using the preprocessor directive `#include "HEADERNAME.h/hpp"`
In your case: `#include "Employee.h"`, if your header file is called like that.

You used so called **"Include/Header guards"** which are used to **prevent multiple header inclusions**. Those should be put in the respective header file, not in other header files that include it.
Alternatively you can use `#pragma once`. It's non-standard, but should be widely supported.

For your strings you wanna address the namespace std as such: `std::string`